# What word is appropriate for a single-width slice of the third axis of data?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, technical

We have easy go-to terms for the X and Y axis, as row and column, respectively. However, I have never heard a similar term applying in the Z axis. Does such exist?

Cell is not appropriate, as as cell refers to a specific position, where the word in question would refer to some grouping of cells along the same position in the third axis.

Example:

> Add another ______ to the input for temperature data
>
> *Row* is to *X axis* as ______ is to *Z axis*.

Comment: Well, in general, you would add another *dimension* to the data no matter how many you're starting with.

Comment: @Jim Dimension would refer to the addition of a Z axis to a set of data with rows and columns, but it doesn't fill the suggested role. Look at the example I gave - if you say "dimension" vs. "column", the meaning is *vastly* different.

Comment: Well, I'd probably argue about whether it could lead to confusion or not.

Comment: @Jim I realized I was reading your post wrong, my new comment addresses it more clearly.

Comment: If you have one dimensional data (vector data) adding another dimension would make it 2D and would likely be represented by either columns or rows depending on what you started with.

Comment: @Jim What I am asking is the word used to refer to the Z axis *within* 3D data. Nothing to do with 2D vs. 3D vs. 4D. Adding a column to 2D does not make it 3D, and adding a ____ to 3D would not make it 4D.

Comment: I think you are confusing the representation of 1D, 2D, 3D data with the data itself.  I.e., Yes, in Excel, it may be represented as rows and columns (and of course Excel does not have a 3rd dimension) but data of any dimension can also be represented by points in n-space and those don't have rows or columns at all.

Comment: Perhaps you could use "layer"

Comment: I've puzzled over this question for a few minutes to try to figure out what you're asking. It seems others are similarly puzzled. As far as I can tell, what you are asking is for the word that fills the blank in "row is to X axis as _____ is to Z axis". Is that right?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Yes.

Comment: I've done some more research and there indeed does not seem to be such a term. So if I'm going to make one up, I think I'd avoid layer mostly because it can overlap with other terminology (my specific case relates to 3D graphics, and layers already have a meaning in that). Perhaps some random, similar word with no overlap is the way to go - like "stratum". But I wanted to ask before making such a leap.

Comment: I think the title is part of what was causing confusion, since it seemed to be asking for a name for the third axis itself. I did an edit to clarify that, and to add the more logic-language example that helped me understand your question. I can't think of a better term than “single-width slice” for the title though, which is pretty awkward! I hope that edit helps though.

Comment: You would probably want to ask this on Mathematics SE. Spreadsheets use the idea of a page as a third dimension, graphics would use layers, and you could think of each as a plane where a point is define by (x,y,z). There would obviously be infinite many planes that could be defined.

Comment: @AMR Personally, I'll be satisfied enough to make up a term myself if no one here knows of a general one already existing (which seems to be the case). However, if this has sparked some kind of need to know among anyone, don't let me stop you from asking on Mathematics!

Comment: You don't wanna go with "Z-row", huh?

Comment: I'd go with layer as @Jim suggests. However, with three- (or higher-) dimensional data, "row" and "column" appear highly problematic terms, too, without any unambiguous meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard term.  There is no a strict association between "x axis" and "row".  (For that matter, rows are generally indexed vertically, which would associate them with the y axis, not the x axis.)  A figure (or feature space) with a y axis won't necessarily have anything you could point to as a "row".

Pixel-based images do have rows and columns that are often indexed with y,x values, in which case z often means depth (thus, "layers"), but that's specific to graphics.

If you're talking about matrices, your question was asked on reddit a while back, where the favored (but non-standard) term was "aisle":

https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/1ajrfu/if_a_2d_matrix_has_rows_and_columns_what_is_the/

As others have noted, Excel uses "sheets" for its third dimension, following the paper metaphor.

When working with three-dimensional data sets, the third dimension is defined by the type of data.  For example, hyperspectral imagers create data cubes that are indexed by row (line), column, and band (wavelength or channel). A scientist could say

> "Add another band to the data set for observations at 2.4 microns."

But that's specific to that data type, of course.  Perhaps your best strategy would be to identify the appropriate specific type of dimension for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I would call it a tier.

1. 2. 3. 

column    row       tier
x         y         z
abscissa  ordinate  applicate

(Excuse the horrible formatting: Apparently this site doesn't use MathJax.)